# Is the multiplicative Chernoff bound stronger than additive one?

Tags: probability, inequality

The multiplicative Chernoff Bound says for $X_i \in \{0,1\}$ that satisfies $\mathbb{E}[X_i] = p$,
$$
\mathbb P\left(\sum\limits_i^n{X_i} \geq np(1+\delta)\right) \leq e^{-\frac{1}{3} np\delta^2} \>.
$$

The additive version says that 
$$
\mathbb P\left(\sum\limits_{i}^nX_i \geq np+n\epsilon \right) \leq e^{-2n\epsilon^2} \>.
$$

I wonder if the multiplicative version could be stronger. Let $\epsilon = p \delta$, then the additive Chernoff bound is reduced to 
$$
\mathbb P\left(\sum\limits_{i}^{n}{X_i} \geq np(1+\delta)\right) \leq e^{-2np^2\delta^2} \>.
$$ This is a much weaker bound when $p \ll 1$.

How can these two versions of Chernoff bounds have such a difference? I mean, which step in deriving these two bounds diverges, causing the fact I have illustrated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No version is stronger than the other. Look at the proofs of both statements and you'll notice (e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound) that one case uses $1+x\lt e^x$ while the other does not. This explains the divergence you mention.

Answer (score 0):

The addictive one is stronger than the multiplicative one, since the multiplicative one can be derived from the addictive one.You should see the derivation in this material www.cs.berkeley.edu/~sinclair/cs271/n13.pdf‎ . The multiplicative one emerge as a corollary of the addictive one.

Comment: This isn't what the OP means by "stronger". The OP is asking about how tight the bound is relative to the true probability.

Comment: The original material: https://web.archive.org/web/20160627043226/https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~sinclair/cs271/n13.pdf

Comment: Though I do not see how the multiplicative one is a corollary of the additive one. From what I see, they are both corollaries of a more general version.

Answer (score -1):

Here is one proof of the additive Chernoff bound you mentioned. Let $t$ be any positive real number. We have

$$
\begin{align*}
\Pr\left[ \bar{X} > p + \epsilon \right] & = \Pr\left[ \exp\left( t \sum_{i = 1}^n (X_i - p) \right) > \exp( t n \epsilon ) \right] \\ 
& \leq \frac{ \prod_{i = 1}^n \mathrm{E}[ \exp(t(X_i - p)) ] }{\exp(tn\epsilon) }  \\
& \leq \frac{ \prod_{i=1}^n \exp( t^2/8 ) }{\exp(tn\epsilon) } \\
& = \exp( n(t^2/8 - t\epsilon) ),
\end{align*}
$$
where second inequality is due to Markov's inequality, the last but one inequality is due to Hoeffding's lemma by considering $(X_i - p)$ as a random variable. By setting $t = 4\epsilon$, your additive version of Chernoff bound is achieved.

Since Hoeffding's lemma holds for any random variable with domain $[a, b]$ such that $b - a \leq 1$, it does not make most use of domain $[0, 1]$. Hence it is weaker. And this explains why it is much weaker when $p \ll 1$.

The multiplicative Chernoff bound you mentioned is derived by the multiplicative one in [Chernoff Bound, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound) which does not use Hoeffding's lemma in its proof. And the proof is subject to the domain $[0, 1]$.

Considering the multiplicative and additive ones in Wikipedia.  I think the additive one is technically stronger than the multiplicative one since the multiplicative one uses one more relaxation like @ivan said.